# Что нам даёт явное указание имени хоста в методе listen инстанса Server модулей http/https NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Если посмотреть определения TypeScript-типов модуля HTTP, то их вариантов использования метода `listen` довольно много:

```
listen(port?: number, hostname?: string, backlog?: number, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(port?: number, hostname?: string, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(port?: number, backlog?: number, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(port?: number, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(path: string, backlog?: number, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(path: string, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(options: ListenOptions, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(handle: any, backlog?: number, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
listen(handle: any, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
```

Что же нам даёт явное указание `hostname` по сравнению со случаем, когда этот параметр не указан?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явное указание hostname дает вам ограничение на то, какие сетевые интерфейсы и как именно вы хотите прослушивать.
В целом, ответ на ваш вопрос дан вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715797/how-to-use-the-optional-hostname-parameter-in-node-js-server-listen) и вкратце он звучит просто: да, вы можете слушать всё, что вам заблагорассудится и так как вы этого хотите, но хорошей практикой является указание конкретных параметров прослушивания порта и хоста, так как могут измениться и сетевые настройки и конфигурация устройств.

Вы можете работать с несколькими сетевыми интерфейсами смотрящими в разные сети. Сетевые интерфейсы будут иметь свои адреса, а так же могут иметь свои DNS. Таким образом слушая один лишь порт, вы будете слушать вообще всё, что на него придёт.

Или вам наоборот необходимо слушать всё одним колбэком: [слушать несколько хостов одним колбэком](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188303/listen-to-multiple-hosts-with-http-server-on-node-js) (например смотреть в интрасеть по одному адресу, а в интернет - по другому, но отдавать контент одинаково).

Иногда в localhost отдают детальную информацию по запросу (раскрывая информацию по ошибке детально), а "наружу" сугубо то, что нужно (код и общее сообщение).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Прошу прощения, но похоже Вы не получили награду. Это так?
Она должна была присудиться автоматически. Если Вы не получили награду, то я решу этот вопрос - дайте мне знать.